# How to create a six character password in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

I need to create a user with a six character password in new MySQL on my mac. I know that the lowest setting in 5.7 will allows only eight characters. Is there any way to go around that?

I type in `CREATE USER 'newsier'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'special'`

It outputs the error

```
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

Comment: This seems a strange question. If you dont want password validation to run, dont load the plugin

Comment: How do i not load it. Because it showed up default in 5.7

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - How do we unload the plugin?

Comment: `SHOW PLUGINS;` will show you the plugins installed and if you want to uninstall one the command is `UNINSTALL PLUGIN plugin_name`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the [password validation plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password-plugin.html). By default it only allows 8 characters and longer passwords. Because it can't check the value of a hash, @RiggsFolly is correct that pre-hashing the password will work.

However, if you want to [change the options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password-plugin.html#validate-password-options-variables), you'll need to set the value of the `validate_password_length` system variable. You can do this in the configuration file or:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password_length=6;
```

Comment: This does NOT seem to work in mysql 5.7.11 for mac installed via brew. I get the same error even after changing the options.

Answer (score 40):

First you login with `mysql -u root -p` and check the current policy rules by:

```
# SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 5      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

Then you can change any of the above variables at your will:

```
# SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 5;
# SET GLOBAL validate_password_number_count = 0;
# SET GLOBAL validate_password_mixed_case_count = 0;
# SET GLOBAL validate_password_special_char_count = 0;
```

Finally you can create a database and a user accessing it with a simpler password:

```
# CREATE DATABASE test1;
# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test1.* TO user1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "pass1";
# FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that you can login with `mysql -u user1 -p test1` using password `pass1`

Comment: This is the right answer. The error 'ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements' could be because of `mixed_cese_count` or `special_char_count`. Wherever I read it said, change the pass length, but it was about mixed_case. Thanks!

Comment: For MySQL ver 8.0.26-0, the code is like `SET GLOBAL validate_password.number_count = 0;` instead of an underscore within it.

Answer (score 6):

**MySQL 5.7+** by default haves a **Password validation system**. In case if you don't want to go strictly with the policy and need to assign your own then just disable the password validation and restart **mysqld** process.

Edit **my.cnf** file :

```
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

in **[mysqld]**

```
validate-password=off
```

Save the file and then **restart** the process

```
sudo service mysqld restart
or
systemctl restart mysqld
```

and then **change the Root Password** using the following and follow the steps it won't throw exception for the Root Password.

```
mysql_secure_installation
or
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

If you are doing **installation** for the **first time** and want to know the **temporary password** then use the following to find the **first time password**:

```
 grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Let me know your comments on the same, in the below comment box.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to entirely disable the password "plugin" that seems overly strict by running the following:
`uninstall plugin validate_password`

Should you need it again you can turn it back on via:
`INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so'`

Optionally, you could disable it, set your password and re-enable it:

```
uninstall plugin validate_password;
CREATE USER 'newsier'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'special';
INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
```

Further reading:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-plugin-loading.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password-plugin-installation.html

Answer (score 3):

Check current password policy rules by

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

Now set new value of those variable:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 6 ; // that you like
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = LOW ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can get round it by using a pre hashed password like this :-

```
CREATE USER 'newsier'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
       AS '*0D3CED9BEC10A777AEC23CCC353A8C08A633045E';
```

But that does mean you need to hash `special` correctly before this will actually set a password that you can then use the plain text version of.

Answer (score -2):

This might help:

`GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS'yourpassword';`