# How do I turn off the mysql password validation?

Tags: mysql, validation, global-variables, mysql-5.7, change-password

It seems that I may have inadvertently loaded the password validation plugin in MySQL 5.7. This plugin seems to force all passwords to comply to certain rules.

I would like to turn this off.

I've tried changing the validate_password_length variable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913583/2341218) to no avail.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_length=4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'app' = PASSWORD('abcd');
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

I would like to either unload the plugin or neuter it somehow.

Comment: Have you tried changing the policy setting? `SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;`

Comment: `SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;`

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Here is what I do to remove the validate password plugin:

1. Login to the mysql server as root `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`
2. Run the following sql command: `uninstall plugin validate_password;`
3. If last line doesn't work (new mysql release), you should execute `UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';`

> I would not recommend this solution for a production system. I used
>   this solution on a local mysql instance for development purposes only.

Comment: to re-enable it again, use following command:  
`INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';`

Comment: To remove the plugin you will need to set up a secure password at least once via `grep 'password' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -1` and then `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`.  After doing so you can run the commands from srayhunter above then run `mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass` to use any password you would like.

Comment: The plugin is called `cracklib_password_check` in current MariaDB.

Comment: Note: In MySQL 8.0.4, the validate_password plugin was reimplemented as the validate_password component. Instead of the #2 query above, run: `UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';`

Comment: Removing the module itself is not the proper solution. You can retain the feature by lowering the security policy.

Comment: `mysql> SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = 0;`

Answer (score 84):

For mysql 8.0 the command to [disable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-installation.html) password validation component is:

```
UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
```

To install it back again, the command is:

```
INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
```

If you just want to [change](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-options-variables.html) the policy of password validation plugin:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = 0;   # For LOW
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = 1;   # For MEDIUM
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = 2;   # For HIGH
```

Answer (score 35):

Building on the answer from Sharfi, edit the /etc/my.cnf file and add just this one line:

```
validate_password_policy=LOW
```

That should sufficiently neuter the validation as requested by the OP.  You will probably want to restart mysqld after this change.  Depending on your OS, it would look something like:

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

validate_password_policy takes either values 0, 1, or 2 or words LOW, MEDIUM, and STRONG which correspond to those numbers.  The default is MEDIUM (1) which requires passwords contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, one digit, and one special character, and that the total password length is at least 8 characters.  Changing to LOW as I suggest here then only will check for length, which if it hasn't been changed through other parameters will check for a length of 8.  If you wanted to shorten that length limit too, you could also add validate_password_length in to the my.cnf file.

For more info about the levels and details, see [the mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password-options-variables.html#sysvar_validate_password_policy).

---

For MySQL 8, the property has changed from "validate_password_policy" to "validate_password.policy".  See the updated [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-options-variables.html#sysvar_validate_password.policy) for the latest info.

Comment: If you only need a temporary change, to allow a single password to be set, you could use `SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;`

Comment: This is a better solution than removing the module itself.

Comment: mysql: unknown variable 'validate_password_policy=LOW'

Comment: Looks like the variable name has changed in the latest MySQL.  @Amalgovinus, try using the variable name "validate_password.policy" instead and see if that works for you.  And if it does, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

To reply to your question: How do I **turn off** mysql password validation?

Short answer: You can reduce the complexity.

Login to Mysql Client as a root.

```
set global validate_password.policy = LOW;
set global validate_password.length = 2;
set global validate_password.mixed_case_count = 0;
set global validate_password.number_count = 0;
set global validate_password.special_char_count = 0;
```

Proceed with `create user ...`

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot to set simple password on my local machine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

To disable password checks in mariadb-10.1.24 (Fedora 24) I had to comment out a line in **/etc/my.cnf.d/cracklib_password_check.cnf** file:

```
;plugin-load-add=cracklib_password_check.so
```

then restart mariadb service:

```
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall:

```
mysql> uninstall plugin validate_password;
```

An uninstalled plugin is not displayed by `show plugins;`

Install:

```
mysql> install plugin validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
```

Disabled by configuration:

```
[mysqld]
validate_password = OFF
```

A plugin can be disabled by configuration only if installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure this in mysql configuration file
open `/etc/my.cnf` file
In this file all the lines which is configuring the password policy make those commented like

```
#validate-password=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
#validate_password_length=10
#validate_password_mixed_case_count=1
#validate_password_number_count=1
#validate_password_policy=MEDIUM
```

Uncomment and change the value of the properties you want to change.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make exceptions, you can apply the following "hack". It requires a user with [`DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/uninstall-plugin.html) and [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/install-plugin.html) privilege for `mysql.plugin` system table.

```
uninstall plugin validate_password;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'app' = PASSWORD('abcd');
INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
```

Bland security disclaimer: Consider, why you are making your password shorter or easier and perhaps consider replacing it with one that is more complex. However, I understand the "it's 3AM and just needs to work" moments, just make sure you don't build a system of hacks, lest you yourself be hacked

Answer (score 2):

Further to the answer from ktbos:

I modified the mysqld.cnf file and mysql failed to start.
It turned out that I was modifying the wrong file!

So be sure the file you modify contains segment tags like [mysqld_safe] and [mysqld].  Under the latter I did as suggested and added the line:

```
validate_password_policy=LOW
```

This worked perfectly to resolve my issue of not requiring special characters within the password.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem on Ubuntu 18.04 on Mysql. When I needed to create a new user, the policy was always high.

The way I figured out how to disable, for future colleagues who come to investigate, was set to low.

Login to the mysql server as root

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Set the new type of validation

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=0; //For Low
```

Restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: You must write this "SET..." command to mysql shell. Not to bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

For references and the future, one should read the doc here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-password-validation.html

Then you should edit your `mysqld.cnf` file, for instance :

```
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Then, add in the [mysqld] part, the following :

```
plugin-load-add=validate_password.so
validate_password_policy=LOW
```

Basically, if you edit your default, it will looks like :

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
plugin-load-add=validate_password.so
validate_password_policy=LOW
```

Then, you can restart:

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

If you forget the `plugin-load-add=validate_password.so` part, you will it an error at restart.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Things have been a bit different in MySQL 8 *(But in fairness, technically for the better)*.  I gave up on trying to remove the password on my local MacOS install.  So, I realized that if you can't beat 'em, join 'em!

Here's my quick & dirty solution:

- installed MySQL8 via HomeBrew (by default, installs as insecure)
- edited my ~/.zshrc *(because that's the shell I use.  others might use .bash_profile or other)*

  - `nano ~/.zshrc`
- added 2 alias lines

  - `alias mysql='mysql -uroot'`
  - `alias mysqladmin='mysqladmin -uroot'`
- pushed changes by

  - `source ~/.zshrc`

So now, rather than worrying about using the `-u` or `-p` flags, they're automatically used on `mysql` or `mysqladmin` commands.

FYI, this should also work if you DO have a password.  You'd simply include the `-pPASSWORD` in your alias.
(ex: `alias mysql='mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD'`)

Additionally, you could add additional alias lines if you use any other `mysql` commands.

**FYI: DO NOT take these steps on a Production server.**
*I'd like believe that goes without saying... but, just in case you didn't know better.*

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your MariaDB server using the command

```
mysql -u root
```

or

```
mysql -u root -pYOURPASSWORD
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket';
```

and

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score -1):

On some installations, you cannot execute this command until you have reset the root password. You cannot reset the root password, until you execute this command. Classic Catch-22.

One solution not mention by other responders is to temporarily disable the plugin via mysql configuration. In any `my.cnf`, in the `[mysqld]` section, add:

```
skip-validate_password=1
```

and restart the server. Change the password, and set the value back to 0, and restart again.

Comment: this doesn't work. Can you mention which mysql version this applies to?

Answer (score -2):

For mysql 8.0.7, Go to your mysql directory, and then use:

```
sudo bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

to configure the password option.

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'organizer'@'localhost'  WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'organizer'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

no need to stop/start mysql