# MYSQL Password Trouble

Tags: mysql, plugins, passwords

I cant login into mysql, already did multiple tries on mysql_secure_installation.

Tried changing the password directly from the mysql.user table like this:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-manage-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line/

Already tried removing the password plugin:
[How do I turn off the mysql password validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301100/how-do-i-turn-off-the-mysql-password-validation)
Still didnt let me login...

Removed the password plugin, then did the mysql_secure_installation
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Info: Mysql was installed on apt, already tried purging and installing again
Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

PROBLEM: sometime mysql will make your root user use unix plugin for auth
ERROR 1698 (28000)

Answer (score -1):

first try to remove all

[askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql)

```
 sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
 sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

now

[Re install Mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)

easy beasy

Comment: still not working
~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'